# Working of Mockito's verify and argument captor

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I'm trying to test the following method

```
public void saveToMultipleSources(MyObject myObject)
{
    if (myObject.isOfSomeType()) {
        firstDAO.saveObject(myObject);
        myObject.setContent(null);
    }
    secondDAO.saveObject(myObject);
}
```

The test I wrote was

```
@Test
public void testSaveFeature()
{
    //initialize all objects
    obj.saveToMultipleSources(myObject); //myObject has a valid content.
    Mockito.verify(firstDAO).saveObject(myObject); 
    myObject.setContent(null);
    Mockito.verify(secondDAO).saveObject(myObject);
}
```

But on running, I get the error that expected and actual arguments differ for the verify statement of firstDAO. The expected was an object with valid content but actual arguments invoked are with Content set as null. I tried the exact same thing with ArgumentCaptor as well, but got the same results.

Can someone explain why does Mockito behave this way? I tried logging the entire object and can see valid Content being set just before I call the firstDAO.

Also how do I go about testing this?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //initialize all objects
> obj.saveToMultipleSources(myObject); //myObject has a valid content.
> Mockito.verify(firstDAO).saveObject(myObject);
> ```

The problem is that setting the objects content to `null` is a side effect of your method. In consequence Mockito compares the recorded parameter (having valid content) with the object modified by your method (having content already set to `null`).

> In that case, how can I test this? – Abhilash Panigrahi

In the test Make  `myObject` a `Mockito.spy()` and prevent the execution of `setContent()`:

```
@Test
public void testSaveFeature()
{
    //initialize all objects
    MyObject spyOfMyObject = Mockito.spy(myObject);
    doNothing().when(spyOfMyObject).setContent(null); // special null matcher may be needed...

    obj.saveToMultipleSources(spyOfMyObject); 

    Mockito.verify(firstDAO).saveObject(spyOfMyObject); 
    Mockito.verify(spyOfMyObject).setContent(null);
    Mockito.verify(secondDAO).saveObject(spyOfMyObject);
}
```

But you most likely want to be sure that `myObject.setContent(null);`
is called before econdDAO.saveObject(myObject);`...

```
@Test
public void testSaveFeature()
{
    //initialize all objects
    MyObject spyOfMyObject = Mockito.spy(myObject);
    doNothing().when(spyOfMyObject).setContent(null);

    obj.saveToMultipleSources(spyOfMyObject); 

    Mockito.verify(firstDAO).saveObject(spyOfMyObject); 
    InOrder inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(spyOfMyObject,secondDAO);
    inOrder.verify(spyOfMyObject).setContent(null);
    inOrder..verify(secondDAO).saveObject(spyOfMyObject);
}
```

Comment: So what you mean to say is that although the actual invocation is with the content, since null is being set to the object in the course of the execution of the method to test, I am getting the error? In that case, how can I test this? Or how can I edit the src so that test becomes easier? I'm not in favor of creating a deep copy of the object and setting the content attribute as null for the copy object.